# froala editor not working in django templates

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg, froala

i am making a blog site. So, i installed froala wysiwyg text editor, the problem that i am getting is that froala toolbar is visible in admin but not in templates. here is what i am doing

my models.py

```
from froala_editor.fields import FroalaField
class Cards(models.Model):
    desc = FroalaField(theme="dark", null=True,blank=True)
```

my forms.py

```
class CardsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Cards
    fields = ['desc']
```

i think i have done everything else in settings.py and urls.py because froala toolbar is visible in admin panel. 
I don't know what i am doing wrong.. please help

Comment: Can anybody please help!! i am still stuck

Comment: i have not got any answers till now.. but i have resolved this issue. the problem was with jquery.. froala editor is not supporting new version of jquery, so i used jquery 1.1 , and now everything is working fine.. hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

you mean to say froala wysiwyg text editor is not visible for the form you had set
if it is so just use this :
make sure that you are using custom form textarea and check id is there are or if there is id

kidly also check there is not js error
    
 $(function(){
                                                        $('#id_content').froalaEditor({"inlineMode": false, "imageUploadURL": "/uploads/froala_editor/images", "imageUploadParams": {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": getCookie("csrftoken")}, "fileUploadURL": "/uploads/froala_editor/images", "fileUploadParams": {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": getCookie("csrftoken")}})
                                                    });